# VB.NET print pointer of COM Objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, interop, marshalling

I want to print the memory address of my .NET compiled object imported with DLL.
The code for pinned object are (googling):

```
' dim managed variable
Dim primitiveObject As String="HELLO WORLD"
' pin variable and create
' GC handle instance
Dim gh As GCHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(primitiveObject , GCHandleType.Pinned)
' get address of variable
Dim AddrOfMyString As IntPtr = gh.AddrOfPinnedObject()
Console.WriteLine(AddrOfMyString.ToString())
' free the handle and unpin variable
gh.Free()
```

This code works perfectly, but my .NET Compiled object is not primitive type.

```
Dim myComObject as New MyDLL.MyNETObject
```

How to print myComObject memory address?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A core feature of COM is that the *implementation* of a COM interface is completely invisible.  Only the interface pointers have a meaning, starting with IUnknown*.  You can technically see the method pointers from the interface pointer, but they may well be pointing to a proxy of the interface, code that talks to another machine half-way around the world.

Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown() may look attractive, but that represents the Runtime Callable Wrapper instance, not the actual COM object.

You should thus never try to obtain such a "memory address", it has no meaning.  And for that matter, as meaningless as the address of a managed object that isn't pinned anymore.